# How to mock a single method for a class?

Tags: c#-4.0, rhino-mocks

I'm new to using a Mocking framework to mock objects for unit testing. I'm currently using Rhino Mocks and I would think it would have a method to do what I'm not finding it.  Here is a LinqPad program (just copy and paste it in a C# program query and it will just work) that shows what I'm trying to do:

```
public interface MyTest{
    int A(int i);
    string B(int i);
}

/// This is an actual class that is a black box to me.
public class ActualClass : MyTest {
    public int A(int i){
        // Does some work
        return ++i;
    }

    public string B(int i){
        return A(i).ToString();
    }
}

/// I'd like to create a mocked class that uses an instance of the actual class 
/// to provide all of the implementations for the interface except for a single method
/// where I can check the parameter values, and provide my own return value, 
/// or just call the actual class
public class MockedClass : MyTest {

    private ActualClass _actual;
    public MockedClass(ActualClass actual){
        _actual = actual;
    }
    public int A(int i){
        if(i == 1){
            return 10;
        }else{
            return _actual.A(i);
        }
    }

    public string B(int i){
        return _actual.B(i);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var mock = new MockedClass(new ActualClass());
    mock.A(0).Dump();
    mock.A(1).Dump();
    mock.A(2).Dump();
    mock.B(0).Dump();
    mock.B(1).Dump();
    mock.B(2).Dump();
}
```

---

Results:

```
1
10
3
1
2
3
```

What do I do to mock this out for unit testing.  Do I need some sort of Dependency Injector?

Comment: You meant how to create class using Rhino mock to replace MockedClass?

Comment: @CuongLe Yes.  There are lots of methods in my actual class and I don't want to hand implement them all, even if it is boiler plate code.

Comment: why dont you try inheritant MockedClass: AactualClass then you don't need to add useless method?

Comment: What are you actually trying to test? If you're trying to test `ActualClass`, then you don't need `MockedClass` (which implements the same interface as `ActualClass`), you need a mock class for the **dependencies** of `ActualClass`.

Comment: @voithos I'm trying to test some business logic that makes 100's of calls on the ActualClass.  One of the calls involves some active directory user logic that returns a bool if it is valid.  I can't replicate in our test environment, so effectively just want to return a true instead of an error.

Comment: @Daryl: The problem with just mocking out a single method is that you're no longer doing unit testing, it's more like integration testing. If a logic error is made in some of the non-mocked calls, generally you won't be able to differentiate that from a logic error in the class under test.

Comment: @voithos I'm trying to test (Unit, integration, call it what you will) a single method in a business library that accepts this "MyTest" Interface. The method I'm trying to test will call the MyTest interface object quite a few times, and I just want to stub out some test data for one of those calls, depending on the parameters entered.  My example is a hardcoded method that will work, I just figured there was a better way than hard coding the Mocked Class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the return value of a mocked object based on the parameters passed in.  I wouldn't take the approach of mixing a real dependency and a mocked dependency -- too much opportunity for a bug in the real dependency to creep in to your testing.

Here's an example you could use on your MyTest interface that examines the input argument of the mocked method and sets a return value accordingly:

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyTest>();
mock.Stub(m => m.A(Arg<int>.Is.Anything))
    .Return(99)
    .WhenCalled(mi =>
                    {
                        var arg = Convert.ToInt32(mi.Arguments[0]);
                        switch (arg)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                mi.ReturnValue = 10;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                mi.ReturnValue = 20;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                mi.ReturnValue = 30;
                                break;
                            default:
                                mi.ReturnValue = -1;
                                break;
                        }
                    });
```

Note that the "Return(99)" is needed because when you stub a method that returns a value, Rhino.Mocks **requires** that you either define an exception to be thrown or define a return value.  Even though we don't use the return value (since we provide our own inside the WhenCalled handler), it still must be defined or Rhino.Mocks will thrown an exception the first time the stub is called.